# Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    import axios from 'axios'

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons';

const getAll = () => {
    return axios.get(baseUrl);
}

const create = (newObject) => {
    return axios.post(baseUrl,newObject);
}

export default {
    getAll:getAll,
    create:create
}
```

Using axios to fetch data from server(in reactjs from json server), everything works fine but console shows this warning:
`Line 13:1:  Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default.`
How to remove this warning??

Comment: Another way I like to go about this is just export each method individually (for example: `export const getAll = ...`) and then import them all under a namespace like so: `import * as api from './path/to/my/api'` -- then you can call `api.getAll()`, etc.

Comment: You really should use named exports here instead of default-exporting an object.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to assign the object to a variable before exporting it as default.

```
const exportedObject = {
     getAll,
     create,
};

export default exportedObject;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also export the function individually to get rid of the warning:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons';

export const getAll = () => { return axios.get(baseUrl); }
export const create = (newObject) => { return axios.post(baseUrl, newObject); }
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can remove this warning by just adding the comment "// eslint-disable-next-line" before export.

import axios from 'axios'

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons';

const getAll = () => {
    return axios.get(baseUrl);
}

const create = (newObject) => {
    return axios.post(baseUrl,newObject);
}

// eslint-disable-next-line
export default {
    getAll:getAll,
    create:create
}
```

Comment: Disabling ESLint Rules Is Not At All Recommended As It Helps To Boost Efficiency & Cleanliness Of Our Code. Instead Always Try To Find A Solution To Fix Those Warnings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).