# Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default

Tags: javascript, image, constants

I am building a restaurant website and got this error in my constants/images.js
this is my full page of images.js :

```
export default {
  bg,
  chef,
  G,
  gallery01,
  gallery02,
  gallery03,
  gallery04,
  knife,
  logo,
  menu,
  overlaybg,
  spoon,
  welcome,
  findus,
  laurels,
  award01,
  award02,
  award03,
  award05,
  sign,
  quote,
  gericht,
};
```

the error shown in exporting default, kindly I need your help :)

Comment: Can you add the error to your question?

Comment: Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default

Comment: Check [Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738988/assign-object-to-a-variable-before-exporting-as-module-default-warning)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.